# JSF graphicImage onclick problem

Tags: java, ajax, jsf-2

You know sites with internationalization flags that you click and get the language you want. This is the task I want to achieve with JSF tags.

EDIT: Nothing happens when I press the language icon.

This is my xhtml.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"> 

<f:view locale="#{lang.locale}">
<h:head>

    <h:outputStylesheet name="style.css" library="css"/>
</h:head> 
<h:body>
<div id="flags">
    <!-- NOT WORKING !!! -->
    <h:graphicImage name="#{lng.flag}" library="images" styleClass="flag">
        <f:ajax event="click" execute="#{lang.swapLocale()}"/>
    </h:graphicImage>
</div>
```

This is the Language class. As you will see is a simple class which swaps between 2 languages (Bulgarian and English).

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Locale;

import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.faces.event.ActionEvent;

public class Language implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5964917570659286475L;

    private boolean isBulgarian = true;
    private final Locale BG = new Locale("bg");
private final Locale EN = Locale.ENGLISH;


public Locale getLocale() {
    if(isBulgarian) {
        return BG;
    } else {
        return EN;
    }
}

public void swapLocale() {
    System.out.println("SWAP LOCALE");
    switchLocale();
}

private void switchLocale() {
    isBulgarian = !isBulgarian;
    Locale newLocale;
    if (isBulgarian) {
        newLocale = BG;
    } else {
        newLocale = EN; 
    }
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().setLocale(newLocale);

}

}
```

Here are the faces-config.xml and web.xml

faces-config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<faces-config version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
 xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_0.xsd">

 <managed-bean>
  <managed-bean-name>lang</managed-bean-name>
  <managed-bean-class>jsfDP.language.Language</managed-bean-class>
  <managed-bean-scope>session</managed-bean-scope>
 </managed-bean>

 <application>
    <resource-bundle>
        <base-name>language</base-name>
        <var>lng</var>
    </resource-bundle>
 </application>

</faces-config>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>DesignPatternsWithJSF</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.faces</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Comment: What's the problem? Putting `<!-- NOT WORKING !!! -->` isn't nearly enough, esp. since it is hard to spot.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing what your exact problem is, just a guess:

You're using AJAX to switch the language, but I don't see the view getting rerendered. In that case the switch might occur but if the view isn't updated you won't see it.

Assuming the whole page needs to be updated anyways, I'd suggest wrapping the image with a commandButton that executes the swap and doesn't use AJAX (which would be unnecessary here).

Comment: 10x I will try to wrap the image.

Comment: Found my mistake... my *.properties files were named language_bg.properties and language.properties. When I changed the second one with language_en.properties everything worked.

Dummy mistake... sorry for bothering you.